# C# Mono start process with pipe command in linux

Tags: c#, mono

In windows, pretty easy to send pipe via cmd.exe, I simply write

`.FileName = "cmd.exe";` and

`.Arguments = "d:\ifme\addons\ffmpeg\ffmpeg -i d:\Videos\sata.mp4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f yuv4mpegpipe - 2> nul | d:\ifme\addons\x265\x265lo -p medium --crf 28 -f 523 -o d:\ifme\temp\video.hevc --dither --y4m -";`

but in Linux (Ubuntu 14.04.1) I write:

`.FileName = "/bin/bash";`

`.Arguments = "-c /home/anime4000/Desktop/ifme/addons/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i /home/anime4000/Videos/sata.mp4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f yuv4mpegpipe - 2> /dev/null | /home/anime4000/Desktop/ifme/addons/x265/x265lo -p medium --crf 28 -f 523 -o /home/anime4000/Desktop/ifme/temp/video.hevc --dither --y4m -";`

I got `FFmpeg` error which is no command specified...

I use create file method:

`System.IO.File.WriteAllText("cmd.sh", "/home/anime4000/Desktop/ifme/addons/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i /home/anime4000/Videos/sata.mp4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f yuv4mpegpipe - 2> /dev/null | /home/anime4000/Desktop/ifme/addons/x265/x265lo -p medium --crf 28 -f 523 -o /home/anime4000/Desktop/ifme/temp/video.hevc --dither --y4m -");`

`.FileName = "sh";`

`.Arguments = "cmd.sh";`

I got an error which is `x265lo` file not exist, but file was there with execute permission

So, how to get proper pipe command with C# Mono?

Note: `x265lo` is a 8 bit BPP build, `x265hi` is a 16 bit BPP build, because contain two x265 with different BPP

Answer (score 1):

(Sorry, this should be a comment but I don't have enough reputation here.)

I don't know what's wrong specifically, but you should be able to determine how Mono calls your shell by doing something like this:

```
strace -fv -s4096 -e trace=execve /path/to/your/program args-to-your-program
```

Once you have done this, please update your question with the relevant `execve()` lines.